# Synonymized tags does not show up in the list of tags when it is partially typed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This bug applies to any page with a tag editor (ask question, edit question, edit tags, etc.). The synonym tags do not show up in the list of available tags when the name is partially typed.

Using [assassination-classroom](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassination-classroom) as an example, it currently has [ansatsu-kyoushitsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansatsu-kyoushitsu) as synonym. However, [ansatsu-kyoushitsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansatsu-kyoushitsu) doesn't show up when `ans` is typed in the tag editor.

This totally defeats the purpose of having Japanese tag synonyms, as they are supposed to help user to find the correct series tag.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

<s>The desired behavior is the current behavior in the search box of [tags listing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags).</s> It turned out that it is also buggy.

While the search box works with [ansatsu-kyoushitsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ansatsu-kyoushitsu), it doesn't work with [the-legend-of-koizumi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-koizumi) when searching for `koi` (it is a synonym of [mudazumo-naki-kaikaku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mudazumo-naki-kaikaku)).

Comment: This is quite odd. If you type in `anime`, [retag] comes up, but for your example and for `attack-on-titan` it definitely doesn't work.

Comment: The tag completer is behaving correctly on all the other sites I tried, but not here. No idea what's going on; could be related to the synonymization spree I went on yesterday...

Comment: @senshin: Assassination Classroom synonym was applied for a long time. (Well, I flag for mod to create it, though)

Comment: @nhahtdh Right; I was just thinking that maybe something broke internally from so many synonyms being created in a short period of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, good find.

This is a four-year-old bug that affected master (i.e. target of synonym) tags containing hyphens.

A fix will be pushed out shortly.

Comment: There are 2 bugs in this report: you fixed the first bug in the tag editor screen, but the bug in the tag listing is not yet fixed. While the second bug is of lower priority, would you please take a look at it?

Comment: After looking at the code, it's a much more involved fix.  Will try to work on it in the next few days.

Comment: Should I make a separate bug report for the similar bug in tag listing?

Comment: I'm taking another crack at this - it's just some very, very old code that needs a bit of refactoring before the fix can be applied.

Comment: Alright, it looks to be fixed now; after cleaning up the code, the fix wasn't that difficult after all!

Comment: It seems that the problem is fixed. However, the current behavior is that a keyword can search across `-`. Is this the expected behavior? (For example `san` matches `princess-and-the-pilot`)

Comment: Yes, in order to quickly find tags, we store a version of the tag without the hyphen.